# How can I return Execution plans of a set of SQL queries located in a txt file, using Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, nullpointerexception, sql-execution-plan

I need to retrieve some information, sequentially, from the execution plans of a set of SQL queries stored in txt file. I have more than 2000 SQL queries so I need a program to do this.

I've tried with Java, but I have a problem with this piece of code:

```
public class GenerateQueriesPlans {      
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {  


    SQL d= new SQL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver","DB2ART","@@@@");


    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String fileName=chooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString()+File.separator+chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
         String Stmt_ToExecute="EXPLAIN PLAN FOR "+strLine;
         System.out.println(Stmt_ToExecute);
         String Stmt_Output="SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());";
         System.out.println(Stmt_Output);
         d.executeQuery(Stmt_ToExecute);
         d.executeQuery(Stmt_Output);                        
          while (d.rs.next()){
            System.out.println(d.rs.getString("PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT"));
          }

       }
    }
}
}
```

I got a `NullPointerException` on the second While line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: JFileChooser on the `public static void main` thread?!?!?!  Please read the first three web pages of the Sun/Oracle Swing tutorial, and look into `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.  If you need a long running item (the SQL Select) use a `SwingWorker`.  These practices cannot be learned too early, as you will cost others more work than you are paid if you don't understand about drawing on a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type is your variable degined as SQL, but it seems like d.rs returns null, hence your null pointer .  Maybe you need to check for null before starting your secord while:

```
 if (d.rs!=null) {
   while (d.rs.next()){
     System.out.println(d.rs.getString("PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT"));
   }
 }
```